# upstart compile issue

Tags: compiler-errors, makefile, configure, upstart

i am trying to compile upstart for my server and i am able to

```
./configure
```

but just after that,

```
make
```

shoots back this error

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I looked around and some people alluded to there not actually being a 'Makefile', that is without an extension. The only files I find are 'Makefile.am' and 'Makefile.in' and there should be an additional 'Makefile' from what I can gather. I changed the name of the 'Makefile.in' to 'Makefile', but that doesn't do. Probably not right, either. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the `configure` step failed.  That should normally generate the makefile from the input files you've found.  Did you notice any errors from running that script?

Comment: ah... "No package 'libnih' not found" and then "Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix." and so i shall "See the pkg-config man page for more details."

Comment: just changed the PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the value '/home/MYUSER/upstart-1.6.1' and same thing... not sure.

Comment: It wants to know where your libnih is, not your upstart source.

Comment: yes, i am now going through the motions... installing cmake so i can then install d-bus, required by libnih ... thanks for your help!